# Solving a mathematical question in PHP/HTML without Javascript

Tags: php, html, forms

Im kind of new to programming (taking a course currently) and our task over the weekend is to build a website (really basic) where we have to solve a addition of 2 random numbers. I was able to create those random numbers, but what with is, to create something like a field the user (in this case me) has to fill out and "submit"; and then the website should show my own anwser and the correct one. The issue im facing in addition to that is, that when i create a submit function the website refreshes and those random numbers change each time.

My code looks like this (forgive me for using german terms):

```html
<?php
$zufallszahl = rand(1,100) . "+";
$zufallszahl1= rand(1,100);
$solution= bcadd($zufallszahl,$zufallszahl1);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Homework Taschenrechner</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Additionen</h1>
    <hr>
    <h4>Addiere die folgenden Zahlen:</h4>
    <p> <?php echo $zufallszahl; echo $zufallszahl1 ?> <p>
    <form method="post">    
        <input type="number" name="Usereingabe" min="0" placeholder="Deine Antwort">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I would really appreciate a "simple" solution, I googled this issue already for an hour, but most solutions are just too complicated for me right now, and i end up not understanding what the code is about. So just to sum up, I would like to know how to create a submit field that doesnt refresh the website so the random numbers stay and a field that "checks" the answer and says its true/false.

Comment: So what is the form for?

Comment: Im not sure to be honest; i suppose its unecessary if youre asking?

Comment: "a submit field that doesnt refresh the website" ...for that you need AJAX, which in turn requires JavaScript (which you said for some reason you don't want). But then again, you could fairly simply ensure that it doesn't replace the random numbers by saving them somewhere (e.g. in hidden fields) so they are submitted with the rest of the form, and then when the server receives the postback it can read the numbers and do the calculation based on those. Find a simple HTML/PHP forms tutorial, it'll help you grasp the key concepts.

Comment: @PopescuIon the form is for the user to give their answer to the question, so the computer can check it.

Comment: in this case why does the code print the 2 numbers?

Comment: @PopescuIon the user is supposed to add them together and submit the answer.

Comment: @Popesculon The user is supposed to give the `SUM` of the two numbers as the answer in the form which should then be validated to see if the answer was correct or not.

Comment: @MikailKilic tbh though it would be a lot simpler to do the whole thing in JavaScript... unless the purpose of the exercise is specifically to teach you about forms and postbacks?

Comment: @ADyson clearly a forms and postbacks. However I'm just surprised on the number of bugs on initial go.

Comment: @ADyson I suppose thats a valid question, its just that we didnt do any JavaScript yet, so im completely clueless how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although, if you were allowed to use JS, it would be a lot simpler. However, since you wanted it in just PHP, the code below should work. Feel free to modify it as per your needs

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['zufallszahl']) && !isset($_POST['zufallszahl1'])) {
    $zufallszahl = rand(1,100);
    $zufallszahl1= rand(1,100);
    // $solution= bcadd($zufallszahl,$zufallszahl1);
} else {
    $zufallszahl = $_POST['zufallszahl'];
    $zufallszahl1 = $_POST['zufallszahl1'];
    $solution = bcadd($zufallszahl,$zufallszahl1);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Homework Taschenrechner</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Additionen</h1>
    <hr>
    <h4>Addiere die folgenden Zahlen:</h4>
    <p> <?php echo $zufallszahl . " + "; echo $zufallszahl1 ?> <p>
    <form method="post">    
        <input type="number" name="zufallszahl" value="<?php echo $zufallszahl; ?>" readonly />
        <input type="number" name="zufallszahl1" value="<?php echo $zufallszahl1; ?>" readonly />
        <input type="number" name="Usereingabe" min="0" placeholder="Deine Antwort" value="<?php echo $_POST['Usereingabe'] ?? ''; ?>">

        <button>Check Answer  </button>

       <?php if(isset($_POST['Usereingabe'])){ ?>
           <?php if($_POST['Usereingabe'] == $solution)
                    echo "Correct Answer";
             else {
                   echo "Wrong Answer. Correct answer is $solution";
            } ?>
       <?php } ?>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE**
If you are using version below `PHP 7`, just use `<?php echo isset($_POST['Usereingabe'])? $_POST['Usereingabe'] : ''; ?>` in place of `<?php echo $userSolution ?? ''; ?>`

Comment: The first `else` will fail and will throw undefined index notices. Plus, an "action" is required for the form.

Comment: Funk Forty Niner are you sure about that?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thanks for the heads up, I've edited my answer. However, the form can be submitted without an `action`

Comment: @GetSet Heh, yeah sorry. You're right (about the `else`). Must've been having a brain fart LOL!!! My bad. However, an action is required for the form. I've been corrected a few times by [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) about that.

Comment: @MD.TabishMahfuz This has 2 names `<input name="solution" type="number" name="Usereingabe"`. Plus, `?? ''` is PHP 7 exclusive as a ternary operator.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner A form's `action` attribute is no longer required since HTML5. `<form>` is valid and submits the data to the same page that the form is present on.

Comment: @kerbholz I guess I'm going to have to ping Barmar sometime about this, seeing that he reopened a question I closed not too long about something related to that. I'm aware of what you say, I'm just confused as to why Barmar thinks otherwise.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner You can ping me too if you get an answer and don't forget, I'd like to know too. I got my info from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner cross-browser concerns likely

Comment: @MD.TabishMahfuz awsome thank you! It seems to work, there are some 'new' commands im unaware; but ill just look them up and try to understand what their purpose is.

Comment: Glad i could help!

Answer (score 0):

So you can keep them in a _SESSION variable and when they submit the answer you can check the _POST variable against the _SESSION one

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Usereingabe']))
{
   if($_POST['Usereingabe'] == $_SESSION['sol']){
      $check = "correct answer";
     }
   else
    { $check = "wrong answer"; }
}
else {
$zufallszahl = rand(1,100) . "+";
$zufallszahl1= rand(1,100);
$solution= bcadd($zufallszahl,$zufallszahl1);
$_SESSION['zufallszahl1']=$zufallszahl1;
$_SESSION['zufallszahl']=$zufallszahl;
$_SESSION['sol']=$solution;
}
// do anything else u want
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Homework Taschenrechner</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Additionen</h1>
    <hr>
    <h4>Addiere die folgenden Zahlen:</h4>
    <?php if(isset($check)) { echo $check; } ?>
    <p> <?php echo $_SESSION['zufallszahl']; echo $_SESSION['zufallszahl1']; ?> <p>
    <form method="post" action="*your file.php*">    
        <input type="number" name="Usereingabe" min="0" placeholder="Deine Antwort">
        <button type="submit">Submit!</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can add other things to it depending on your needs

Comment: I didnt downvote you but a session is not needed for this problem. It could be used by why bother.

Comment: This won't work given you are generating a new random number and placing it in the session variable prior to validation.

Comment: @John it can be checked if the answer is wrong/correct in order to see if other numbers need to be generated. As I said, he can adapt the program depending on his needs

Comment: The random number is regenerated each time the page refreshes and you place this in the session variable. You then validate the post data against that new random value and NOT the previous random value. Your code is replicating the same problem the original poster is currently having. You need to move $_SESSION['sol']=$solution; after the if statement to make your solution work.

Comment: @GetSet, never trust the client is one reason to bother.

Comment: @John true indeed.

Answer (score -1):

You could use two extra input tags in your form of `type="hidden"` that contain the random numbers in their value fields, and check if they are empty. If they are, generate new ones, otherwise keep the old ones.

Comment: Could you show an example of what you intended to mean because im not following. I didnt downvote you by the way/

Comment: @GetSet See the answer provided by MD.Tabish Mahfuz [https://stackoverflow.com/a/58571327/12277291]